# Redux-form-Material-UI Datepicker field issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I'm getting an error whenever I try to render a Field from Redux-form-material-ui. This is my form code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { TextField, DatePicker, SelectField } from 'redux-form-material-ui';

class InputForm extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <form>
                <div>
                    <Field name="eventDate" component={DatePicker} format={null} hintText="What day is the event?"/>
                </div>    
            </form>
        )
    }
}

InputForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'contact'
    })(InputForm);

export default InputForm;
```

The error that I'm getting is this one:

*Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `ConnectedField`.*

I know it has to do with the `component={ DatePicker }` assigned on the Field element because if I change it to TextFIeld it renders okey.

Comment: put the code for `ConnectField` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that DatePicker hasnt been implemented(do not know why) on the new release of redux-form-material-ui@next. So this has been solved.

Comment: You can create your own custom component

Comment: Ashish, and how is that? Could you explain yourself a little bit more?

Comment: https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/submitvalidation/... See the renderField in the link... `input` type has been used over there you can use material ui `picker` over there ...